# How to enable NEON acceleration with dlib on arm?

Tags: arm, neon, dlib

I notice that the latest version of dlib supports neon acceleration on arm. I've tried it on iphone6, with performance enhancement from 35ms to 28ms per frame (360X360). That is abnormal, since I've achieved a ten times speedup on the laptop with SSE2 acceleration (640X480). Does anyone know the reason of it?

Answer (score 2):

Give GCC the `-mfpu=neon` switch.